# Implementing session-based security in Java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm developing a local project with Tomcat, Servlets and JSP. This project is going to be a simple, single-login blog with a backend where the admin can login and create posts and pages. I'm getting stuck in a situation where I need to enforce a session check for every servlet that is going to be present in the admin section. Upon successful admin login, I create a session flag that is going to be checked on every admin page as a security measure.

Now, since the only two methods that are going to be used for a servlet in this case are either doGet or doPost, should I create a method to check the admin session in each servlet and then call that method before each doGet/doPost, or is there a better implementation possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It's better to use filters instead of checking session in each and every servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Filters` can solve your problem. In your `web.xml` add filter and implement it as you wish.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Sample Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.example.SampleFilter
    </filter-class>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Sample Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) if you want to avoid reinventing the wheel. It has a bit of a learning curve, but the basic usecases can be covered with very [simple configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html). There is [good quality documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/springsecurity.html) and lots of tutorials/articles available.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, and I've bookmarked the links you mention. But right now I'm learning Java from the ground up, hence the stopover at servlets.